# PHP for loop stops too early

Tags: php

I have a loop which increments the limit of the content which is showing on a website (json content).

The problem is that the loop stops at 50. The links that are generated with the incrementation are working fine when I'm calling them in the browser. The content is shown.

But I store only the content of the first 50 and then it stops.

```
public static function getAllCustomers() {
    $rest = Rest::getInstance();
    $spaces = self::getSpaces();
    $customers = array();
    $path = SpacePath::buildPath();
    for ($i = 0;
    ; $i += Paths::$MAX_CONTENT_LENGTH) {
        $temp = $path . '?start=' . $i . '&limit=50';
        $content = Helper::toArray($temp);
        print_r($temp);
// print_r(empty($content['results']));
        if (!empty($content['results'])) {
            foreach ($content ['results'] as $space) {
                if (!preg_match('|^(.*?)-([0-9]+)|i', $space ['name'], $matches)) {
                    continue;
                }
                $customer = (object) array(
                            'name' => $matches [0],
                            'ident' => $matches [1],
                            'id' => $matches [2],
                            'space_key' => $space ['key'],
                            'options' => array()
                );
                $customers [] = $customer;
            }
            break;
        }
    }
    print_r($customers);
    return $customers;
}
```

Comment: Very little information to run with, using functions which to us are just black boxes. you might want to rethink this whole thing through...

Answer (score 0):

Here, let me reformat your code so you can see what relates to what...

```
public static function getAllCustomers() 
{
  $rest = Rest::getInstance();
  $spaces = self::getSpaces();
  $customers = array();
  $path = SpacePath::buildPath();

  for ($i = 0; ; $i += Paths::$MAX_CONTENT_LENGTH) 
  {
    $temp = $path . '?start=' . $i . '&limit=50';
    $content = Helper::toArray($temp);
    print_r($temp);
    //print_r(empty($content['results']));

    if (!empty($content['results'])) 
    {
      foreach ($content ['results'] as $space) 
      {
        if (!preg_match('|^(.*?)-([0-9]+)|i', $space ['name'], $matches)) 
        {
          continue;
        }
        $customer = (object) array('name' => $matches [0]
                                  ,'ident' => $matches [1]
                                  ,'id' => $matches [2]
                                  ,'space_key' => $space ['key']
                                  ,'options' => array()
                                  );

        $customers [] = $customer;
      }       
      break; // oops
    }
  }
  print_r($customers);
  return $customers;
}
```

You'll notice I added a comment to your break statement. ;)